# using exceptions and writing data to files in python 3

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, syntax

here what I need to do:

Your program must raise an exception if the user chooses any item not on the menu 
presented. Along with raising an exception, write the code to handle this exception.

Ask the user for a value to convert.Your program must raise and exception, and handle the exception, if an input 
errors occurs

Perform the conversion and write the original value, the original unit, the 
converted value, and the converted unit to an output file named 
conversions.txt.

Repeat steps a and b 10 times (in a loop).

heres my code:

```
#imports

import os

# global variables
mile_choice = 1
gallon_choice = 2
pound_choice = 3
inch_choice = 4
fah_choice = 5
quit_choice = 6

mainfile = open('conversions.txt', 'w')

# intro and global name variable

name = input ('what is your name? ')
print()
print('hello',name,', today we will be doing\
some standard to metric conversions.')

#define main function
def main():

    choice = 0

    while choice != quit_choice:

             display_menu()

             print()
             choice = int(input('Please enter a number 1 - 6 : '))\

             if choice == mile_choice:
                    print()
                    miletokm()

             elif choice == gallon_choice:
                    print()
                    galtolit()

             elif choice == pound_choice:
                    print()
                    poundstokg()

             elif choice == inch_choice:
                    print()
                    inchtocm()

             elif choice == fah_choice:
                    print()
                    fahtocel()

             elif choice == quit_choice:
                    print()
                    print('Exiting the program.')




#define functions
def display_menu():
    print()
    print('          Menu          ')
    print()
    print('Press 1 for Miles to Kilometers')
    print()
    print('Press 2 for Gallons to Liters')
    print()
    print('Press 3 for Pounds to Kilograms')
    print()
    print('Press 4 for Inches to Centimeters')
    print()
    print('Press 5 for Fahrenhiet to Celisus')
    print()
    print('To exit please enter 6 ')



def miletokm():
     invalid_attempts = 0

 #while loop for invalid input limited to 3

    while invalid_attempts < 3 and invalid_attempts >= 0:
        print()
        mile = float(input('how many miles would you\
 like to convert to kilometers? '))
        mainfile.write(str(mile) + '\n')

 # if statement to determine weather to proceed with conversation
 # valid input = conversion
 # invalid input =  return with + 1 to invalid_attempt count

    if mile >= 0 :

        print()
        mile_conv = mile * 1.6
        print('that would be:', format(mile_conv, '.2f'), 'kilometers.')
        print()
        mainfile.write(str(mile_conv) + '\n')
        return mile


    else:

        print()
        print ('invalid input')
        print()
        invalid_attempts += 1
```

I left out the other conversion def. to help keep it shorter.

I am having problems with the exception part first and for most.
I have tried various things but I cant figure out how to write out the code correctly
I know how to define a value error for a number entered outside of the menu range
I don't understand how to write the units along with the data entered to the file.
The way I Have it now, it is not writing any information to mainfile.

I also feel like my code is very sloppy written. I have no idea because my professor refuses to help me.

I know that's alot to run through but i really have no where else to turn. I don't understand how I should structure the code and how to effectively accomplish what I need done.
what I have read covers the basis of this but I have no examples to look at other than very simple simple examples that deal with strictly one thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like... (from http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions)

```
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
...         break
...     except ValueError:
...         print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. First thing that you need to do is to handle better the value for `choice` that the user gives you. Check what happens if they give you `9` or `'foo'`.

Next, you should do the same for every value received in your functions that convert units. For that, you use `try/except` as @bitfish showed you (except that you use `input` instead of `raw_input`).

Comment: ok so i used the try/except in my program but here's the thing. if a string is entered it kicks to my except clause. if a number is entered  out of the range of my menu numbers. the program just prints the menu again. How do i get it to kick to the except clause?

Comment: You have `if` and `elif`, but you don't have an `else`. In the `else`, you can handle an out of range number.

Answer (score 0):

1. close the files you open (`mainfile.close()`)
2. doing this `elif choice == quit_choice:` inside of this `while choice != quit_choice` makes no sense
3. use `'\n'` to skip lines (`print('\n')` is the same than `print()` two times

there are many ways to solve such a problem, white the experience you'll acquire you'll find more elegant ones, but this one is already ok.